# how to call diffenet attribute of a Pandas dataframeusing a variabe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

consider df is a pandas data frame with 10 different columns and 500 rows. user is asked to pick a column name which will be stored in var1.
I am trying to call the corresponding column to var1 and change the data type but I see an error. 
is there anyway to solve this problem?
Regards,

```
var1=input('Enter the file name:').lower().capitalize()
df[var1]=df.var1.astype(float)
```

error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'file_name'

Comment: Do you mean: `df[var1]=df[var1].astype(float)`? What happens if the user picks the wrong (typo) column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current approach you're taking - using `df.var1` to reference the `var1` column - has pandas searching literally for a column/attribute named `var1`. A correct way of accessing this column/attribute would be to use something like this `df[var1]`, which will look for whatever is contained in `var1`. See the example below for more detail:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> var1 = 'hello'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'hello': [1]})
>>> df
   hello
0      1
>>> df.var1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/blacksite/Documents/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'var1'
>>> df.hello
0    1
Name: hello, dtype: int64
>>> df[var1]
0    1
Name: hello, dtype: int64
```